# MongoDB $near Returning Max Results with Max Distance

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I have the following mongo query (written in PHP)

```
 $q = array("created_at" => array("\$gte" => $mdate), "icv" => 1, "loc" => array("\$near" => array($latitude, $longitude), "\$maxDistance" => 5));
```

Which is basically:

```
db.collection.find({loc: {$near: [XX,YY]}, $maxDistance: 5}, "vid": 1, "created_at":{$gte: "SOMEDATE"}});
```

I would like to find ALL the documents that match this query, not just the 100 that it returns by default. If i set the `limit` on this query, it goes out side the distance distance.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In [this mailing list post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/O_RjL_8tgZA/v9Gs9Ieox6IJ), Eliot mentions that `$near` does not use a cursor, so its results are limited to either 4MB or 100 documents, whichever is reached first. The [current documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/near/) says the same, but this is true only for 2d indexes (the documentation should be fixed by [DOCS-1841](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-1841)).

If you are storing points in [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#id2) and using [2dsphere indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/) (new in version 2.4), `$near` queries do utilize cursors and should not have a hard upper limit of 100 documents.

Consider the following examples, first using a 2d index:

```
> var point = [0,0];
> for(i=0;i<200;i++) db.foo.insert({x: point});
> db.foo.ensureIndex({x: "2d"});
> db.foo.find({x: {$near: point}}).count(true);
100
> db.foo.find({x: {$near: point}}).limit(200).count(true);
100
```

Then using a 2dsphere index with equivalent point data:

```
> var point = {type: "Point", coordinates: [0,0]};
> for(i=0;i<200;i++) db.bar.insert({x: point});
> db.bar.ensureIndex({x: "2dsphere"})
> db.bar.find({x: {$near: point}}).count(true)
200
> db.bar.find({x: {$near: point}}).limit(150).count(true)
150
```